# Problem on using .on(click) inside .on(change)

Tags: javascript, jquery

in this code when i select an option and after that click on button everything is ok but when i select another option and then click on button it first execute for perevius option! then for recent one. how can i fix it?
(i need to put my onclick inside onchange function)

```
$("select").on("change", function (e) {
    let i = 1;
    console.log(this.value);
   
    $("button").click(function () {
      console.log(i++);
    });

  });
```

output is like this:

> option1 1 2 3 4
>
> option2 5 1

Comment: Could you add snippet, please? I'm not so clear what the `option1` and `option2` means in the output.

Comment: _"(i need to put my onclick inside onchange function)"_: this maybe the root of your problem. Can you update your question to add a [mcve] as it's a little difficult to work out what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to have only one event handler, you have to remove any previous ones, you can use `.off()` to remove an event handler.

```
$("select").on("change", function (e) {
    let i = 1;
    console.log(this.value);
   
    $("button").off('click').click(function () {
        console.log(i++);
    });
});
```